# Should the tag (fractions) be a synonym of (rational-numbers)?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I have noticed that in the [list of suggested synonyms](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) there is a suggestion to synonymize [fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractions) and [rational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers). See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/rational-numbers/synonyms).

I am not sure this is a good idea. For example, I can imagine question tagged as [limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limit)+[fraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fraction) (if it is a question about a limit of the type $f(x)/g(x)$), but if the same question would be automatically retagged to [limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limit)+[rational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers), it would look strange to me.

I would like to know the opinion of other MSE users whether they consider this tag synonym to be reasonable.

I did not find some older discussion about this on meta, but I found [this discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/fractions-and-rational-numbers) in chat.

Comment: A also oppose synonymization of these.

Comment: I think they should not be synonyms. Not only because of the syntax vs. semantics difference, but also because the term "fraction" is used in many other fraction fields besides $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I'm against this too. When a post is appropriate for the tag *fraction*, it usually falls into following cases:
$$\begin{align}
1.& \text{elementary - i.e. for students who haven't touched the concept of rational number.}\\
2.& \text{specific - i.e some specific subset/representation of rational numbers. e.g. Egyptian fractions.}\\
3.& \text{others - constructs that has nothing to do with rational numbers, e.g field of fractions.}\end{align}$$
IMHO, the overlap of the applicable domain for these two tags are pretty small.

Comment: I agree with Gerald, Bill, and Achille, and would like to add that having looked over some of the articles tagged [tag:fractions], I saw that many of them were concerned with manipulation of expressions of the form $A\over B$, and had nothing at all to do with rational numbers.

Comment: Shouldn't we remove the pending synonym proposal?

Comment: @barto I am not sure whether something like that is possible. The users with score 5 or higher in (rational-numbers) tag can downvote the proposal. (I cannot vote - I do not have enough upvotes in the particular tag.) It says that: *Suggestions will be automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.* (To be approved, they need score of 4.)

Comment: Mod-votes are binding there too.

Comment: After the synonym between the two tags was created, a post requesting the removal of the synonym was posted [in the tag-management thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/20779#20779). However, a separate post on this question might have more visibility.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since it might not be entirely clear what the votes on the question mean (e.g., some user might just vote +1 = it is a good thing to bring up), I will post a separate answer where users can vote whether they are for or against the synonym.

Vote for this answer if you think that [fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractions) **should not** be a synonym of [rational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers).

Comment: Does the fact only one of the answers CW mean something?

Comment: I wanted to mark both of them CW. I must have forgotten to check the box.

Comment: Well, I hope that you didn't shoot Kevin Spacey after checking what was in the box! :-P

Comment: I have marked this answer as accepted after the tag-synonym [was removed by a moderator](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/20779#20779).

Answer (score 0):

Since it might not be entirely clear what the votes on the question mean (e.g., some user might just vote +1 = it is a good thing to bring up), I will post a separate answer where users can vote whether they are for or against the synonym.

Vote for this answer if you think that [fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractions) **should** be a synonym of [rational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers).

Comment: Please don't do this, Rings of fractions exist not only for $\,\Bbb Z,\,$ so it makes no sense to restrict the meaning of fractions in this way.

Comment: @Asaf Possibly. One should also consider the closely related ([tag:localization]) tag.